# Inconsistent SUM when using OVER PARTITION in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a static table, I'm trying to run the following query in SSMS (to get the latest transaction for each user and sum the dollar value):

```
SELECT
    SUM(nMoney) As TotalMoney
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nGroup, nUser ORDER BY dTransaction DESC) AS SEQNUM
    , nMoney
    FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
) MySubquery
WHERE MySubquery.SEQNUM=1
```

This is a table with 2,701,510 rows and the nMoney column is of type Decimal(12,2).  When I run it multiple times, I get a varying result:

```
2317367341.75
2317370443.45
2317449819.62
2317360649.43
2317449819.62
```

What could be causing the inconsistent result?

Comment: Duplicate rows for `nGroup, nUser, dTransaction` might be one explanation. Does `SELECT nGroup, nUser, dTransaction FROM YourTable GROUP BY nGroup, nUser, dTransaction HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` return any results?

Comment: @Martin Smith: It is looking like you may be correct.  I thought these would be unique but there are 102 with duplicates.  I'll continue to investigate.  Post an answer to this question and I'll mark it as the answer if it turns out to be correct.

Comment: If you add a tiebreaker in such as `ORDER BY dTransaction DESC, PrimaryKey` to get a deterministic selection does that stop the issue?

Comment: Duplicates is the issue.  I could add more to the `ORDER BY` until I get unique entries.  But, maybe a better way to do it (since determining the duplicates is tricky) is first aggregate to `nGroup` and `nUser`, select the first records, and then aggregate again.

Comment: But won't that give you the same problem that selecting the "first" records requires some unique definition of first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For floating point arithmetic the order that numbers are added in can [affect the result](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/05/13/417153.aspx).

But in this case you are using `Decimal(12,2)` which is precise.

The issue is that with duplicate values for `nGroup, nUser, dTransaction` the `ROW_NUMBER` is not deterministic so different runs can return different results.

To get deterministic behaviour you can add guaranteed unique column(s) into the end of the `ORDER BY` to act as a tie breaker.